# Standard Error of Truncated Fisher's z Transform

Tags: correlation, standard-error, asymptotics, fisher-transform

I have a question regarding data following the truncated Fisher's z-transform. I currently understand that the correlation coefficient data, after the unbounded Fisher's z-transform, has a standard error of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N-3}}$ based on asymptotic approximation. However, I admit that I have limited understanding of the concept of the variance-stabilizing transformation.

I'm wondering if the standard error of sampled data following a half Fisher's z-transform (lower bound truncated at 0, which approximately follows the bivariate half-normal distribution) will be different, and if there are any existing methods or other thoughts on how to approximate it.

I would greatly appreciate any insights on this question!

Comment: What is the purpose of this truncation? Can you give some context or example of its use?